# Move Assignment of a Vector Element not working, Copy Assignment is called instead

Tags: c++, vector, move-semantics

I have a class that is not default-constructable, copy-constructable or copy-assignable. It is move-constructable and move-assignable.

```
struct SG_MotionState {
    frameId_t frameId;
    btTransform transform;
    vector<sgCustomFieldData_t> mCustomFields;
    sgCustomFieldLayout_t & mLayout;
    
    SG_MotionState (sgCustomFieldLayout_t & _mLayout) : mLayout(_mLayout) {}
    // Disable copy
private: // No copying allowed!
    SG_MotionState& operator = (const SG_MotionState & other);
    SG_MotionState(const SG_MotionState & other);
public: // Only moving
    inline SG_MotionState(SG_MotionState&& other) noexcept = default;
    inline SG_MotionState& operator = (SG_MotionState&& other) noexcept = default;

   ... // Impl
}
```

I store instances of this class in a std::vector:

```
data.push_back(std::move(t));
```

Later I wish to replace values in the array, discarding the original values. However when I try:

```
data[position] = std::move(t);
```

The compiler (g++ 10.2) tries to invoke copy-assign
`SG_MotionState& operator = (const SG_MotionState & other)` instead of invoking move-assign
`SG_MotionState& operator = (SG_MotionState&& other)`. How do I do a move assign to a std::vector element?

The relevant parts of the container class:

```
template<typename T, uint MAX_SIZE>
class t2_ringbuffer {
public:
    /// Stores an item in a container that grows in size
    /// until a maxiumum is reached, thereafter it overrides old values
    std::vector<T> data;
    uint zeroIndex;
    
    t2_ringbuffer() : zeroIndex(0) {}
    
    void push_back(T && t) { // Move semantics version
        if (data.size() < MAX_SIZE)
            data.push_back(std::move(t));
        else {
            data[zeroIndex] = std::move(t);
            
            zeroIndex++;
            if (zeroIndex >= MAX_SIZE)
                zeroIndex = 0;
            
            }
        }
   ... // more impl
   }
```

Edit:
Here is the precise error message:

```
temp/rsserver/dataStructures/ringbuffer.hpp: In instantiation of ‘void t2_ringbuffer<T, MAX_SIZE>::push_back(T&&) [with T = SG_MotionState; unsigned int MAX_SIZE = 60]’:
temp/rsserver/sgNode.cpp:550:40:   required from here
temp/rsserver/dataStructures/ringbuffer.hpp:30:20: error: ‘SG_MotionState& SG_MotionState::operator=(const SG_MotionState&)’ is private within this context
   30 |    data[zeroIndex] = std::move(t);
      |    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Edit 2: Properties of class:

```
is_constructible: false
is_trivially_constructible: false
is_copy_constructible: false
is_nothrow_copy_constructible: false
is_move_constructible: true
is_nothrow_move_constructible: true
```

Edit 3: Minimal example:
https://godbolt.org/z/WWorP1

Comment: I find it hard to believe the copy constructor and operator= are called in this case. Are you sure the error is not coming from a different line? By the way, when disabling constructor it's good practice to use `= delete`.

Comment: I've modified the question to have the error message. I've also done `= delete` and it simply changes the error to `error: use of deleted function ‘SG_MotionState& SG_MotionState::operator=(SG_MotionState&&)’`

Comment: Hmm. Kind of a shot in the dark but can you try removing the noexcept qualifiers?

Comment: Can you make a [mcve]?

Comment: Sure!
https://godbolt.org/z/WWorP1

Comment: It appears that turning the reference member of `SG_MotionState` int a pointer allows the program to compile. Eg: `int & mLayout;` to `int * mLayout` int the godbolt example. This makes things even more puzzling

Comment: It makes sense, see my answer, if you don't understand something about it's feel free to put it in a comment on that answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies in the absence of a move assignment operator.
Looking at your class, you have defaulted this operation.

Unfortunately, `= default` means that you get the default behavior, not that this method is created. This is really confusing.

To make this easier to spot I've recently enabled the following clang warning as error on the code base I'm working on: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html#wdefaulted-function-deleted
(Maybe GCC has something similar)

Long story short, if you have a base class or member that doesn't allow this operation, your class can't default this.

In this case, you have a reference as a member, as one can't reassign a reference, one can't provide the assignment operator.

Possible workarounds are: store as a raw pointer, or store as `std:: reference_wrapper`.

PS: please make your deleted methods public and use `= delete`, it will give much better error messages

Comment: Thankyou! I figured out that the reference member was the problem while you were probably typing this up, but really thanks for the in-depth explanation as to why this causes the error.

Comment: Glad to be helping, enabling all your warnings in the compiler really helps, not all make a lot of sense, though, if they don't, you can disable them. You'll learn a lot from that.